# How to evaluate the exit status of bash command in if ... elif structure?

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

I'm new to working with bash script, and this might be simple to do but I'm not sure how to do it.  I have a command that tries to mount a disk at a specific path.  DISK1 is defined as a specific SSD Drive at a specific USB port -- not too important here.

```
/bin/mount DISK1 ${MOUNT_PATH}
```

Now I want to check whether the mounting is successful.  Normally, this expression will return 0 if it's successful, but once in a while there's read error and the expression returns a 32.

```
if [$? -eq 0]; then
   echo "Mounted DISK 1 at ${MOUNT_PATH}"
elif [$? -eq 32]; then
   echo "DISK 1 read error"
else
   echo "FAILED TO MOUNT"
fi
```

When this script ran, and the expression came back as 32, it went to the elif block, but then I got a "command not found" for this.   I assume that because "$?" had already been evaluated, so you can't call "$?" again?

So how would you get it to run the mount expression evaluation again and do a 32 -eq 32 comparison so that it can run the "DISK 1 read error"?

Would storing the evaluation be the way to approach this?  Would this code work?  It was hard for me to test the code since the disk read error takes several days to show up.

```
/bin/mount DISK1 ${MOUNT_PATH}
$mnt_stat = $?
if [$mnt_stat -eq 0]; then
  echo "Mounted DISK 1 at ${MOUNT_PATH}"
elif [$mnt_stat -eq 32]; then
  echo "DISK 1 read error"
else
  echo "FAILED TO MOUNT"
fi
```

Comment: No, you get that error because of a spacing issue.  `[` is not an expression element, it is a bash command, and must have spaces on both sides.

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here.

Comment: To stick with your chosen syntax, I recommend: `[[ $mnt_stat -eq 0 ]]`

Comment: This is not very readable nor intuitive. Check my answer. Isn't this more easy/readable `[[ $mnt_stat -eq 0 ]]` VS `((mnt_stat==0))` ?

Comment: You don't have to wait for a disk failure to test the logic of your shell script.  Just fake the return code by replacing the `mount` command with something like `(exit 32)` to create a sub-shell that returns 32.

Comment: Thank you.  All the comments are super helpful.  I didn't even know that [ is a command "test".  

I'm sticking with the POSIX syntax since I'm not certain this old hardware has bash extension or not.  The original codes seem to be using only POSIX syntax.

Comment: What is the output of `bash --version` ? What is the first line of the script, the shebang ?

Comment: The first line says #!/bin/bash

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: Two tips for learning Bash: the `help` built-in command is a quick way to learn about syntax and built-in commands (e.g. `help [` is faster than finding it in the `man` page), and the `type` built-in can tell you what type of command something is (eg. `type [` or `type cat`).  Bash 5.1 is recent and came out in Dec. 2020 (I'm not sure when 5.1.4 came out).

Comment: If you would read the error message carefully, you would see that it says _**[0** ... command not found. The name of the missing command is the clue. Indeed, if $? is 0, `if` tries to execute the command `[0 -eq 0]`, i.e. it tries to run the command `[0` with the two parameters `-eq` and `0]`, while you want to run the command `[` with the parameters `0`, `-eq`, `0` and `]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run your script in https://shellcheck.net, you will see that `[$mnt_stat -eq 0]` is wrong. You need spaces around `[ ]`, because it's a command.

Also, no space allowed around `=` variable assignation.

---

A proper way, using modern bash:

```
mount DISK1 "$MOUNT_PATH"
mnt_stat=$?
if ((mnt_stat==0)); then
    echo "Mounted DISK 1 at $MOUNT_PATH"
elif ((mnt_stat == 32)); then
    echo "DISK 1 read error" >&2
else
    echo "FAILED TO MOUNT" >&2
fi
```

---

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

`[` or `test` is the `POSIX` test command. It can do simple tests on files and strings. In `bash`, you should use the more powerful `[[` instead and ban `[` for sake of consistency. `[[` can do pattern matching, is faster and safer to use. In this case, we use `((` for arithmetic that is more readable.

See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

---

Don't be confused by spaces. they are mandatory with the form

```
[ ]
[[ ]]
```

because it's some *commands*.

With

```
(( ))
```

it's just an evaluation, so they are no space rules.

Comment: Can I just use mnt_stat like that in if statement and not ((${mnt_stat}==0)).  Also why there are spaces around == for the ((mnt_stat == 32)) and not with ((mnt_stat==0))?

Comment: Use backticks to suround your code in comment. Spaces in `(( ))` are free. What do you mean: _like that_. The sigil `$` is not needed in bash's arithmetic.

Comment: OK, I think I follow you now.  I said "like that" to ask whether the $ is not required and it sounds like it's not needed in bash's arithmetic.  It seems like I need it if I was using:

if [ ${mnt_stat} -eq 32 ]; then

Comment: (( )) seems a lot easier to use than what I was doing.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from some syntax errors (lack of spaces around `[` and `]` and a bad variable assignment), you were on the right track:

> Would storing the evaluation be the way to approach this?

Yes, because each execution of `[` (aka `test`) also sets `$?`, so you'll lose the result of the `mount` command after the first `if` statement runs `[`.

A minimally modified version of your code that works is:

```
/bin/mount DISK1 "${MOUNT_PATH}"
# (exit 32)  # Uncomment to fake a return value.
mnt_stat=$?  # Save return code (no $ sigil before mnt_stat or spaces around the = here).
if [ $mnt_stat -eq 0 ]; then  # Add spaces around [ and ], but ; doesn't need a space.
  echo "Mounted DISK 1 at ${MOUNT_PATH}"
elif [ $mnt_stat -eq 32 ]; then
  echo "DISK 1 read error"
else
  echo "FAILED TO MOUNT"
fi
```